# Can someone explain me why deques are used for the sliding window algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I don't understand the Sliding Window Algorithm that is used to find maximum of subarrays in an Array. When we have a length n Array and we want to print out maximum for subarrays of length k. We can go sequentially through the Array by deques when we push Elements into it and Pop Elements that are not the maximum (I don't know how the removal of deques is handled).

I have seen algorithms that remove from both the front and the end of the deque. But I don't understand why. It is too complicated, so any help explaining me how this algorithm works, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include the specific algorithm that you have seen into the question, for reference?

Comment: Here it is explained https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/#disqus_thread; I can't understand the algorithm. The Code provided there a bit (have a Little bit Knowledge of c++), but not why These deque operations are performed.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you know how a deque works (review it if you don't):

It would be nice if you could first simulate the algorithm with some examples.

I'll try to give you the main ideas (actually, they are mixed in the solution and here as well, sorry), better if you can read them after exercising the algorithm.

For me, the main **trick** is: the deque will keep a list of potential maximum values for the current and **any** upcoming windows.

Because of that, those values should be ordered. But how? Verify below how we can keep the maximum at the front of the deque.

And there is an intention of traversing the array only once [to achieve O(n)]

So, what to do when you have at hand the **next value** of the array?

1. Remove from the deque any other values out of the current window. You can for sure remove them starting from the front. Maybe you won't agree right now, but keep reading and try to understand the next step.
2. Insert this next value at the rear of the deque, throwing away any other smaller values. [here we assure that all deque values are ordered]

But there is good reason for throwing those values away: from now on (for any upcoming window), the current value will always 'beat' any previous smaller values. Cool, isn't it?

Therefore the maximum of the current window is the first item in the deque.